# Hibernate search: Cannot do a wild card search on a dynamically mapped field text fields

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, search, hibernate-search

I have implemented a custom bridge which maps all the dynamic fields with related types. Types can be of FieldType.STRING or FieldType.DOUBLE or FieldType.BOOLEAN based on the value.

When I looked on the mapping on my elastic search schema, all the string fields are mapped with type TEXT where I expect it to be a keyword  so that I can do a wildcard serach.

**Here is my problem** I want to filter "AAA-VALUE" for dynamically mapped field 'attribute.dynamic-field-1'

I have an indexed value as "AAA-VALUE" for dynamically mapped field 'attribute.dynamic-field-1'

If I want to do a keyword search, I faced error like 'Field bridge is not found' then I resolved the error by ignoring the bridge using ignoreFieldBridge and the error is gone.

Then again I tried to do a search with value as "AAA-VALUE" and the result is empty (no data found). Here I created the query using a keyword() query.

Then again I tried to do a phrase query then it got worked but the problem is how I can do a wild card search like '*-VALUE*'.

*Regarding code*, I followed similar implementation as given here https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/legacy/engine/src/test/java/org/hibernate/search/test/bridge/MultiFieldMapBridge.java

Only the type differs in my implementation, where the type can be a string or boolean or double.

**My hibernate search version** - hibernate-search.version and hibernate-search-elasticsearch = 5.11.3.Final

Answer (score 1):

It got to work after doing below changes.

This how I added the fields before

```
public class MultiFieldMapClassBridge implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge {
;
;
;
luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument( fieldPrefix + "." + key, value, document );

}
```

But the fields should be added as below.

```
public class MultiFieldMapClassBridge implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge {
;
;
org.apache.lucene.document.Field field = new org.apache.lucene.document.StringField(fieldPrefix + "." + key, value,  luceneOptions.getStore());
document.add(field);
}
```

I written the wild card query as below

```
queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField(prefixedPath).ignoreFieldBridge().matching(String.format("*%s*", matchingString.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()))).createQuery();
```

I realised this after reading this doc where the class bridges have to add the field as StringField.
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-class-bridge